# Auto add pages to category menu

Tags: categories, menus

I have created a custom post type called Products, on the product pages i have a menu in the left sidebar. This menu is made up of categories for the products.

Is it possible to have my products automatically added to the category menu based the category of the product?

For example, i make a product, i give it a category of blue. Where blue appears in the menu the product will automatically be added underneath blue.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Update:
To be more clear i'm using a plugin called Jquery Accordion Menu and the menu uses a widget. It still uses the built-in wordpress menu system. The Jquery Accordion Widget effectively just styles the menu, in the widget settings you pick what menu you want it to show.

I've found this code inside the plugin file after the comments below. I don't know if it's any help.

```
        function widget($args, $instance) {
            extract( $args );
            // Get menu

            if(! isset($instance['speed']) ){ $instance['speed'] = 'slow'; }

            $widget_options = wp_parse_args( $instance, $this->defaults );
            extract( $widget_options, EXTR_SKIP );

            $nav_menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $instance['nav_menu'] );

            if (!$nav_menu)
                    return;

            $instance['title'] = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base);

            $classMenu = ($instance['classMenu'] != '') ? $instance['classMenu'] : 'menu';

            echo $args['before_widget'];

            if ( !empty($instance['title']) )
                    echo $args['before_title'] . $instance['title'] . $args['after_title'];

            ?>

            <div class="dcjq-accordion" id="<?php echo $this->id.'-item'; ?>">

                    <?php
                            wp_nav_menu(
                                    array(
                                            'fallback_cb' => '',
                                            'menu' => $nav_menu,
                                            'container' => false,
                                            'menu_class' => $classMenu
                                            )
                                    );
                    ?>

            </div>
            <?php

            echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
```

EDIT 2: If i can get this working without the plugin then that's great. I just need some sort of menu that displays categories and the pages for that category automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this plugin that does exactly what i needed.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/collapsing-categories/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Depending on the way you build your menu, you'd have to call the posts like this (fill in placeholders):

```
// Call/Query the posts related to the category:
$your_cat_related_cpts = get_posts( array(
     'post_type' => 'YOUR_CUSTOM_POST_TYPE'
    ,'category' => 'YOUR_CATEGORY'
) );
// Append them to your menu:
foreach ( $your_cat_related_cpts as $content )
{
    echo $content->post_title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 2 Questions. 1) where do i put this code? 2) Will this only work for one category?

Comment: I've tried this in functions.php but it didn't work. It put the post title at the top of every page and it messed up the layout of the page the post is on. It also didn't add it to the menu. I've made the menu by using the built-in wordpress menu system and adding all of the categories to it.

Comment: How about showing your menu code?

Comment: Sorry can you be more specific? I've just used the menu system that comes with wordpress and added categories to it. When you say menu code do you mean the html source code, or something else?

Comment: _HOW_ did you add the menu in your template? The menu won't just pop up if you play around. You need to `add_theme_support()`, define and call the `wp_nav_menu()`, etc.

Comment: I've just used a menu widget to display the menu in a widget area. I didn't use any code in my template to make the menu display. I just added a widget to the sidebar. I'm using a plugin called Jquery accordion menu which is effectively just to style it. I added that widget in the widget section of wordpress and selected the products menu.

Comment: And you didn't tell that you're using a) a widget and b) a plugin? How should we know? Further: Which widget have you used? Basically it's the widgets code that shows the menu, so we need this code and **any related information** to _actually help_ **you**. Am I interested to help you further (and guess a little bit more): No.

Comment: I didn't think it was important. I'm relatively new to wordpress i thought using a widget for a menu was what pretty much everyone did. The plugin only really gives it an accordion effect so i didn't think that was important either. I've found this in the plugins code though i don't know if this is helpful. http://pastebin.com/dwMHccbT